# Can an unpaid parking ticket affect a credit score?

Tags: canada, credit-score

Can a parking ticket from a PRIVATE parking company affect my credit score?

I was falsely ticketed and tried to fight it but the company is being a peanut and sent it to collections. 
If I continue to ignore it, will it affect my credit rating?

Answer (score 6):

If a debt has been offloaded to a collections agency (rightly or wrongly) and the agency reports it to the credit bureaus, yes, that will impact your credit.

Fighting the ticket, fighting the debt with the collections agency, and having the record removed from your credit (if it ever gets reported) are all different problems now.

Comment: Having the record removed from credit report is doable, at least in the US.  Contact your credit reporting bureau, then follow their procedure to dispute the report.  If Canadian credit bureau works the same as the US ones, once your dispute is noted, you can fight the collection of the parking ticket, and possibly the actual ticket, at your convenience.

Comment: oh you are my favourite~ Thanks!!!

If I contact the credit bureau to dispute it and then manage to settle with the collection agency, what would the effect to my credit score/report be? (I'm hoping they will accept the original ticket cost instead of the grossly inflated thing it now is .. I hate DiamondParking so much...)

Comment: @SnyperBunny since its already in collections, before you think about paying the debt ask the collection agency if they will remove your file from your credit report once payment is received. Have that in some sort of writing.

Comment: Should that be in addition to disputing it with the credit bureau?